# Seek event for YouTube player iframe API

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Some context for the question:

1. I know there is no event in the API to track seeking on the
   video.
2. video.js is a very good player but there is no out of the
   box support for youtube. And I didn’t find a reliable enough plugin
   to use.
3. I know it is possible to build custom player controls.
   This is what I plan to do. The problem is that you need to build,
   volume, play, pause, seek, speed, quality, closed caption, etc.

Given that context, I need to reliable track video seeking (from position a to b) if possible using YouTube controls. Any ideas? Some insight?

Comment: @martialdidit seekTo() lets you programmatically seek the video to a certain position.  I need somehow to get notified when the user seeks using the native youtube player UI.

Comment: @Tyler No, I ended up implementing my own UI controls to know when the user seeks.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for the reply. I was afraid I would have to end up doing that. It's silly, many other api's support this., Vimeo and Soundcloud to name a couple. Let's hope they add it at some point.

Comment: @Joe Do you perhaps have some code to share for the custom control where you dispatch a seeked event?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, newer versions of chrome have a plethora of pause events that fire on seek now. I'd expect this will be fixed soon.